# VBA works, but screen doesn't go to cursor

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a Word macro that finds the selected text throughout the document, highlights all occurrences, and returns to the starting point (via a bookmark it sets first). The only problem is, after running it, Word displays the page above the bookmark (where the cursor is). The cursor isn't on screen at all.

After running it, I can tap a key and the screen moves to display the entry point. I added a line to do the same thing within the macro (move right one character), and it still drops me a page above. I tried using SmallScroll on the window, but that moves the insertion point. I need to end up where I started.

What can I do?

---

Sorry about not posting the code before, I couldn't get it to format as code. (I blame IE8 on a federal network.)

```
Sub AcronymHilighter()

''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' Check that user has selected some text
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Dim strGetAcronym As String
If Not Selection.Type = wdSelectionNormal Then
MsgBox "Please select some text.", vbInformation
Exit Sub
End If
'''''''''''''''''''
' Set a bookmark at the current location
'''''''''''''''''''
ActiveDocument.Bookmarks.Add _
    Name:="MarkReturn", Range:=Selection.Range
'''''''''''''''''''
' Save the current track changes state, then turn it off
'''''''''''''''''''
Dim bTrackingAsWas As Boolean

    bTrackingAsWas = ActiveDocument.TrackRevisions

    ActiveDocument.TrackRevisions = False
    ActiveDocument.ShowRevisions = False
''''''''''''''''''
' Find & highlight the text
''''''''''''''''''
strGetAcronym = Selection.Text
Selection.Range.HighlightColorIndex = wdYellow
Selection.Collapse wdCollapseEnd

With Selection.Find
    .Text = strGetAcronym
    .Highlight = False
    .Wrap = wdFindContinue
    .MatchCase = True
Do While .Execute
    Selection.Range.HighlightColorIndex = wdYellow
Loop
End With
'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' Return to the starting point,
' restore Track Changes to the previous state
'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Selection.GoTo what:=wdGoToBookmark, Name:="MarkReturn"
ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=2
ActiveDocument.TrackRevisions = bTrackingAsWas
ActiveDocument.ShowRevisions = True

End Sub
```

Pardon my excessive commenting, I like to remind myself what everything does; the last time I wrote code, it was in BASIC in 1985.

Comment: Can you post the code you have so far so we can help?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not fully aware of your problem (since you didn't post your code), but this bit does the work you described:

```
Sub MarkAndGoBack()
With ActiveDocument.Bookmarks
       .Add Range:=Selection.Range, Name:="Bookmark"
       .DefaultSorting = wdSortByName
       .ShowHidden = False
End With

Dim doc As Document
Dim para As Paragraph

Set doc = ActiveDocument

For Each aWord In doc.Words
   If aWord.Text = "WantedWord" Then aWord.HighlightColorIndex = wdYellow
Next aWord

Selection.GoTo What:=wdGoToBookmark, Name:="Bookmark"
ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("Bookmark").Delete
With ActiveDocument.Bookmarks
       .DefaultSorting = wdSortByName
       .ShowHidden = False
End With
```

End Sub

It searches for the Word "WantedWord" and highlights it yellow. After that, you will be forwarded to your initially created bookmark. It shows the correct page with cursor for me. If you want to do an Input search, you have to replace "WantedWord" with an `InputBox`.